# ConvertFrom-JSON strips array from object

Tags: json, powershell

I'm loading a text file containing some Json to edit a property. However, after modifying the content and writing it to file, the Json becomes invalid.I

I use the following PowerShell to modify the file:

```
$manifest = Get-Content $PathToManifest -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

#modify Json    

Set-Content -Path $PathToManifest -Value ( $manifest | ConvertTo-Json)
```

The following snippet from my Json file gets corrupted:

```
 "contributions": [
    {
      "id": "sample-data-widget",
      "type": "ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget",
      "targets": ["ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget-catalog"],
      "properties": "@{name=Sample Data; description=Create sample data in a VSTS project.; previewImageUrl=img/logo.png; uri=index.html; supportedSizes=System.Object[]; supportedScopes=System.Object[]}"
    }]
```

After loading the Json and writing it back to file the array syntax around targets is gone:

```
  "contributions": [
    {
      "id": "sample-data-widget",
      "type": "ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget",
      "targets": "ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget-catalog",
      "properties": "@{name=Sample Data; description=Create sample data in a VSTS project.; previewImageUrl=img/logo.png; uri=index.html; supportedSizes=System.Object[]; supportedScopes=System.Object[]}"
    }]
```

Why is this happening? Is there a way to make sure the syntax doesn't change?

Comment: Both of you json snippets look the same. Can you show what it looks like before?

Comment: `ConvertTo-Json -Depth 999` ?

Comment: @Matt the top one is before, bottom one below. If you look at the targets property you see that the [ ] around the value are gone.

Comment: @beatcracker if you add that as answer, preferably with some explanation, I'll accept it! It works :)

Comment: I meant that I saw system.object[] on both. That is not part of your original I would imagine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ConvertTo-Json](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849922.aspx) has `Depth` parameter that controls how many levels of contained objects are included in the JSON representation. The default value is `2`. `ConvertTo-Json` will call `.ToString()` on anything nested deeper than specified  `Depth`.

So all you need is to specify sufficiently large number for `Depth` argument or just `([int]::MaxValue)`.

```
Set-Content -Path $PathToManifest -Value ( $manifest | ConvertTo-Json -Depth ([int]::MaxValue))
```

Examples of nesting and `ConvertTo-Json` behavior:

```
$NestedArray = @(1,@(2,@(3,@(4))))
```

Default:

```
$NestedArray | ConvertTo-Json

[
    1,
    {
        "value":  [
                      2,
                      [
                          3,
                          "4"
                      ]
                  ],
        "Count":  2
    }
]
```

No nesting at all:

```
$NestedArray | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1

[
    1,
    {
        "value":  [
                      2,
                      "3 System.Object[]"
                  ],
        "Count":  2
    }
]
```

Desired result:

```
$NestedArray | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3

[
    1,
    {
        "value":  [
                      2,
                      [
                          3,
                          [
                              4
                          ]
                      ]
                  ],
        "Count":  2
    }
]
```